# Error io_setup() failed (38: Function not implemented) in Nginx for ARM M1

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

I have a docker container with nginx. I run it on a macbook with an M1 chip and get the io_setup error() failed (38: Function not implemented).

Comment: You have to have Docker image compatible with your ARM architecture.

Comment: Which docker nginx image is compatible with ARM M1 Chip for MacOS ? It is giving me the same error even though I am writing `FROM --platform=linux/amd64 nginx:1.15.8` on the `nginx.Dockerfile` @czende

Comment: would this one work? https://hub.docker.com/r/arm64v8/nginx/

Comment: @josegp, with `--platform=linux/amd64`, you are explicitly requesting an image that is _not_ compatible with ARM. I think that other image would work; did you try it?

Comment: @JakeRobb thank you for the reply. Yes, I did try that one `arm64v8` image from the link and it worked!

Comment: I didn't understand this, can you please help. The docker is used, so that we can run the same code in any architecture/OS. Then why do we need a different image in this case ?

Comment: Man the whole docker concept really does fall to pieces when you venture outside of the x86 dimension doesnt it.
Are there any work arounds for using the usual x86 container? I'm trying to test a custom container and if I build it for arm, it'll explode the CI. :/

Answer (score 4):

As said in the comments, you just have to run an [NGINX arm64v8 image](https://hub.docker.com/r/arm64v8/nginx/) with:

```
docker run -d -p 8080:80 arm64v8/nginx
```

You can then check that it's correctly running with:

```
curl localhost:8080
```

Answer (score 2):

I have a Mac M1.

My code ran perfectly yesterday, however today after changing nothing it gave this error:

`Error io_setup() failed (38: Function not implemented) in Nginx for ARM M1`.

I tried a bunch of things, but what ultimately worked was simply uninstalling and reinstalling Docker. Sort of a last resort, but it worked for me.

---

EDIT: A few days after this I got a similar error:

`lsb_release command failed with Os { code: 2, kind: NotFound, message: "No such file or directory" }`

that may be related. To fix it, I just quit (closed) Docker Desktop, and re-opened it. That fixed it.

Comment: Same for me, thanks! I already had an ARM64 image.

Answer (score -2):

It seemed to resolve after shutting down postgres which was also using port 8080.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34562449)

Comment: Not sure what you mean. The port number clashes causing the issue. It can be any other App that has already taken the port.